# Powershell script running from usb stick - privileges and arguments

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, usb, portability

I'm making Powershell script that can configure pc's. I'm working with a lot of computers so script is placed on my usb stick, and I'm launching it from it. First I created 2 separated scripts, one when stick was assigned as `D:\` and another when it was `E:\` but it was very frustrating to make changes in both scripts, so I changed it and make it universal for every disk letter. Everything worked fine except commands were script was using built in Windows programs like `netsh` or `cmd`. Adding full path solved the problem, but Script is launching also another script when there isn't specific task in Task Register. I cannot change this second script to add there full path to programs

I've tried: 
1. changing execution policy of launched script
2. changing path to script
3. changing path to powershell (full path)

`bat` file that launch main script:

```
@echo off
SET SCRIPT=path-on-usb-stick\script.ps1
SET PATH="%~dp0%SCRIPT%"
@echo on
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -command "& %path%"
```

Part of the main script which cause problems:

```
if(!(Get-Scheduledtask | Where-Object{$_.TaskName -eq ".check-vpn-new"})) {
        C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command "& 'C:\...\script2.ps1' -Verb RunAs -windowstyle hidden -Wait"
}
```

I'm getting few errors in my output:
1. Arguments in script are `null or empty` but they are not 
2. Script don't have access to files with administrator privileges (even if it's launched with Admin privileges)
3. script don't see `Windows.old` folder which should be cleaned
(everything works fine when script2 is launched from `bat` file)

Comment: `%PATH%` is a system variable, that tells `cmd` where to look for it's executables. Don't mess with it - use another variable name instead (like `MyPath`, `ScriptPath`,...`)

Comment: $script2 = (Join-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -ChildPath 'script2.ps1'); "& $script2 -Verb RunAs -windowstyle hidden -Wait"

Comment: As you've already set the location of the [tag:powershell] script into a variable, it seems as if you should be identifying only the [tag:batch-file] drive letter, not its drive letter and path. You should therefore be using `%~d0\%SCRIPT%`, not `%~dp0%SCRIPT%`. Additionally you should change to this type of syntax, `Set "Ps1PathOnly=path-on-usb-stick\script.ps1"`, and `Set "Ps1FullPath=%~d0%Ps1PathOnly%"`, this means that you're not saving the doublequotes as part of the variable values.